# Suspending Ubuntu Session when Laptop lid is Closed...

Tags: 11.04, laptop, suspend, suspend-resume

I'm using a Toshiba satellite L305 running Ubuntu. One issue, the laptop usually suspends itself when the lid closed, however Ubuntu only does this half of the time, the other half it keeps the system running. Very inconvenient, because when I put my laptop in my briefcase, if it's not suspended, it's just blowing hot air, can't be good for the computer.
I don't think it's a hardware issue, because when I was running Windows on this machine I never had this problem.

Comment: Maybe you have an application running at those sometimes that is preventing the Suspend option?

Comment: hmm... perhaps, I mean it's off and on, is there a way to implement suspension automatically, every time?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest first (unless you have done already)  that you hit the unity button in the corner or win/super key and type Power Management.

Here you should be able to select what action happens when you shut the laptop lid ie suspend/blank screen. It usually works on my laptop but more often than not.

[image: Power Management Options]

Apologies if you have done this already but for some people it is an easier method

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: yes, I've tried this, what I've been doing recently is just manually putting it into suspension before shutting laptop lid, annoying but it works.

Comment: ok sorry.I had one laptop that does that too

Answer (score -3):

search for ACPI fixes, my asus wouldn't suspend, but a few lines of code in a wiki fixed it.

Comment: Winther ..Any chance of you giving Ricochet some of the code that you used. It really would be helpful.